# "ConnectionString " not functioning in visual studio 2012 (with SQL SERVER 2008 express edition )

Tags: sql-server

i'm using visual studio 2012 along with SQL SERVER 2008 express edition.
i wrote a C# program with the following code.
here "SQLExpress" is the instance name that i gave during installation...

```
private void btntest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SQLExpress;Database = Emp;Integrated Security=True";
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }
    }
```

When i build this no errors are being shown..
when i run this no exceptions are being thrown..
but i cannot see any "MessageBox"..

what mistake am i doing here..

edit:
added the entire code.

@Oded
thanks for the help.my problem had been solved.
here's the code for connection string.

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Server=localhost\SQLExpress;Database = Emp;Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: try to learn some C# from any book.
Let us see your full code

Comment: For the server you can try `.` or `local` or `localhost`. You may have the wrong instance name.

Comment: I would remove the try { } al together. It will probably throw an exception and if you can post that we might be able to help out....

Comment: @Oded 
Thanks for the help.
i just had to add LOCALHOST 
and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your connection string

```
  con.ConnectionString = "Server=SQLExpress;Database = Emp;Integrated Security=True";
```

with

```
 connectionString="Data Source=SQLServerNameHere;Initial Catalog=DatabaseNameHere;Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

Use your configuartion instead of *SQLServerNameHere* and *DatabaseNameHere.*

Answer (score 1):

try this

`con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=your server name;User ID = your sql server username;Password=Your Sql Server Password;Initial Catalog=Your database name;Integrated Security=True";`

Comment: thanks for the reply.i just had to use "localhost\SQLExpress" and it worked.

used "@" sign to escape "\"